# Every schoolday or every schooldays?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Let's say you are being asked what is your schedule in school as a student. And you say:

> "My class starts at 8am and it ends at 5pm, they are fixed **every schoolday** or **schooldays**"

I am talking about from Monday to Friday straight. If you take it literally(5 different days), then it will be schooldays right?. On the flipside, if it is as a whole in a week, it is schoolday...(Just my take)

Which is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always use the singular after **every.**  The fact that they are "five different days" is irrelevant, since the whole point of *every* is that they are all the same in this regard.

For example,

> There are fifty dogs in the kennel.  Every dog has a collar.

Each dog is a separate individual, but every *one* has a collar.